# Unable to sudo tasksel

Tags: 12.04, apt, tasksel

When I type the command `sudo tasksel`, I get a list of server packages that I can install. I only have the basic Ubuntu server installed at moment. My version is 12.04. When I select, for example, samba file server and OK it, I get an error. `tasksel: aptitude failed (100)`.

I also get errors trying to `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. (unable to locate package)

I can ping Google and other site and I do seem to have Internet connectivity. How can I fix this?

Comment: seems like your **`Main`** repository is disabled. can you post the output of  `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list` Or run `sudo apt-get update` and try again

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to retrieve the update information.

Try to reconfigure the Packages through

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And try installing through `tasksel`, if still then do the above update command and it will resolve .

Answer (score 0):

Tasksel throws error code `100` because there are errors with the package manager. You can try the following steps to fix it:

1. Update the repository list:

   ```
   sudo aptitude update
   ```
2. Enable the `universe` and `main` repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"
   sudo aptitude update
   ```
3. Try running force install:

   ```
   sudo aptitude -f install
   ```
4. Check for error messages in the installation:

   ```
   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
   ```

   If the above returned an error then you need to first fix it before installing the package using `tasksel`. The following links may be of assistance:

- [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)
- [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)
- [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)
- ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

5. Try purging and reinstalling `tasksel`:

   ```
   sudo apt remove --purge tasksel
   sudo apt install tasksel
   ```
6. Install the package again, using `tasksel`:

   ```
   sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
   ```

That's it! 
Good Luck!